# Upgrading to Tridion 2013 From 2009

Tags: 2013, upgrade

We are planning to upgrade from 2009 to 2013, but before that we want to do a POC on the same.

I have gathered the infrastructure specifications from SDL's documents, but for POC I would like to have your expert comments for minimum requirements of the followings:

We would have three set of servers (1 CM, 1 CD (delivery and Presentation) and 1 Database) for the POC.

OS: 
RAM: 8Gb (Is it minimum?)
Processor:
Hard Disk:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what you want to test with your POC.  If your goal is functionality or you also want to perform load and performance tests.

I would say give your DB the most resources (especially RAM) as possible, since the Publisher and the CM will slow down based on lack of DB resources.

Next, I would give resources to the CM box, because the Publisher runs there and is very CPU hungry.

Finally, I would meet the minimum requirements for CD, but if you're not performance testing on the frontend then you should be fine.

Note:  You might want to setup 1 additional machine as a publisher that can be 'turned on' for the initial bulk publish.  You could also connect this publisher to Dev first, then later to Test, to help make it faster.  Small warning - 1 extra publisher will put extra strain on the DB resources, but you will be able to publish almost 2 times as much content in the same amount of time.

One last point:  Tridion 2009 is 5.4 on a Tridion internal level, whereas Tridion 2013 is 7.0.  There were big changes in architecture between 5.4 and 6.0.  Between 6.0 and 7.0 the architecture is more or less the same and people will not hit many upgrade challenges.  Between 5.4 and 7.0 expect some upgrade challenges with regards to any extensions or TOM API calls, and to carefully test your Content Broker queries.  Check out my article [here](http://www.curlette.com/?p=720) for more tips.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. The link to your article specifies 2011 upgrade, is there any similar link for 2013? Or I can assume minimum differences in upgrading 2011 or 2013 from 2009? Thanks again.

Comment: Everything applies to 2013 as it does in 2011.  Also, if you are having challenges with the upgrade, you might have bette luck searching for Tridion 2011 _issue_ rather than Tridion 2013, since I think more people went first to 2011 from 5.x.